# How to add link to Magnific Popup's javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, magnific-popup

I have the magnific popup on my app and I need help with adding a action to the lightbox. I have added my code to the javascript and outside of it but it never appears inside the lightbox.

I need to add several pieces to the lighbox such as a link that will allow user to make ProfileImage, messages compose box, and short bio of the user. If I can learn how to do one then I am confident I can do the rest.

The action is `<%= button_to('Set as Profile Image', [:avatar, @photo]) %>`

show.html.erb:

```
<h1><%= @user.username %></h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.parent-container').magnificPopup({
            delegate: 'a',
            type: 'image',
gallery:{enabled:true}
        });   
    });


</script>


<div class="parent-container">
    <% @user.photos.each do |photo| %>
        <%= link_to image_tag(photo.image_url(:thumb)), photo.image_url%>
<% end %></div></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell Magnific Popup to open [inline content](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#inline_type) (a div with the image and your extra content), e.g.:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.parent-container').magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a',
        type: 'inline',
        gallery: { enabled: true }
    });
});
</script>

<div class="parent-container">
    <% @user.photos.each do |photo| %>
        <%= link_to image_tag(photo.image_url(:thumb)), "#" + dom_id(photo) %>
        <div id="<%= dom_id(photo) %>" class="mfp-hide">
            <%= image_tag(photo.image_url) %>
            <%= button_to('Set as Profile Image', [:avatar, @photo]) %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

You will need to style the popup; the documentation link above has some sample CSS.

(Apologies if the Ruby code is broken; I'm not really a RoR person.)

Comment: Thank you! That gets it to show the button, however it shows the full-size image as opposed to set size I had specified in the files. My guess is the dom_id is posting the full size?

Comment: Do you mean the image inside the popup? That is controlled by the <%= image_tag(photo.image_url) %> inside the div

Comment: @xps15z I'm guessing `<%= image_tag(photo.image_url(:thumb)) %>` inside the div will show display the image using the thumbnail size. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: I'm still making adjustments meant to it. The `thumb` will make the thumbnail version show. This is how it looked originally http://s29.postimg.org/j9fbgbw6v/Screen_Shot_2014_03_10_at_3_13_56_PM.png . I have it set to show a certain size within the lightbox. It shows the full image with the code you provided. I will ok your answer since it does answer the initial question. Hopefully I can figure out the image sizing soon. Thanks!

Comment: If `dom_id(photo)` is causing the full size image to appear, there are other ways to generate IDs for the divs, e.g. `'photo' + counter`, where `counter` is a loop counter.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [magnific popup documentation](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/), you can load anything you want into the popup (I thought it might have been an image-only "lightbox" plugin)

This means if you place the code you need in your popup div, you should be able to do what you want with it:

```
<div class="parent-container">
    <% @user.photos.each do |photo| %>
        <%= link_to image_tag(photo.image_url(:thumb)), photo.image_url%>
        <%= button_to('Set as Profile Image', profile_path(photo)) %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: I did that before and it only shows the tab on the page, not inside the popup. I took a screenshot http://s7.postimg.org/g3i53b2p7/Screen_Shot_2014_02_19_at_9_14_36_AM_1.png . I prefer to have the tab displaying in the popup and not on the page.